# Session has expired error while using facelets

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am a beginner with JSF and facelets.I have been trying to create a simple login page that uses a facelet template 'master_layout.xhtml'. Everytime I click on Log In,I get the session has expired error with Generated by Mojarra/Facelets .Please help

Here is my login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

   <ui:composition template="./master_layout.xhtml">

   <ui:define name="content">

             <h:form id="myform">
             <h:panelGrid columns="2" right="100px">     

             <h:outputText value="Username    " style="font-size: 20px; color: #C0C0C0"/>
             <h:inputText id="unameTxtBox"  style="position: relative; width:157px"/>


                <h:outputText value="Password    " style="font-size: 20px; color:     #C0C0C0"/>
                 <h:inputSecret id="pwdTxtBox" style="position: relative; width: 157px; "/>

                <h:commandButton id="loginButton" style="right:250px" value="LOG IN"    action="#{loginManagedBean.validateLogin}"></h:commandButton>
              </h:panelGrid>               
             </h:form>             
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="footer">
    Copyright 2011- xyzzz Inc.
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </html>
```

Comment: What error *exactly* did you got and where? Please provide a quote with an entire copypaste of the error. Please also tell which webbrowser you're using and whether the cookies are properly been transferred or not.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what your doing seems to be a straight forward form submit so either the session is being invalidated on form submit (maybe in your action or maybe there is a filter that invalidates it?) or the session timeout is set to something very short in your web.xml deployment descriptor. Have you configured the session-timeout element in your web.xml file? What value did you set it to? If it hasn't been set then the container your are using will use its default value for this.

Comment: I have configured the session-timeout element in my web.xml and set it to 30 .